# how to get a select count(x) from a query of table names

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query the brings back a list of tables and the counts of those tables.

```
select *
from error
```

with a result of

```
tablename | errorcnt
----------+---------
table1    |        5
table2    |      256
```

and so on.
I need to do a `join` so I can get another count from each table as to the records that have been corrected example

```
select count(fixed)
from table1
```

so my new result would be

```
tablename | errorcnt | fixed
----------+----------+------
table1    |        5 |     3
table2    |      256 |   239
```

and so on.
Without doing a cursor how could I do? I guess a sub query using 'tablename'.

Comment: What SQL language are you using? Also: in table1, do you already have a formula for the 'fixed' column?

Comment: Tsql, No that is the problem i tried to do a subquery. select *, (select count(fixed) from tablename where fixed = 'T') from errorcounts

Comment: Can you please post the table structure? Are there particular columns that specifies whether there was an error or whether an error has been fixed?

Comment: The table structure for the error count is as above. Tablename, ErrorCnt the structure for each of the tables to re queried for the count of fixed is Col1, Col2, col3....fixed  i need to get the count of fixed where it is a 'Y'

Comment: This is how i populate my errortable SELECT      T.name TableName,i.Rows NumberOfRows
FROM        sys.tables T
JOIN        sys.sysindexes I ON T.OBJECT_ID = I.ID
WHERE       indid IN (0,1)
ORDER BY    i.Rows DESC,T.name

Comment: Perhaps you could join the two tables on tablename. Better yet, add schemaname to both tables and inner join on tablename and schemaname (or ownername - the point is to guarantee one-to-one joins, taking into account the possibility that two tables can have the same name on your server if they occupy different namespaces).

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 0):

The comment you made:

> This is how i populate my errortable SELECT T.name TableName,i.Rows
>   NumberOfRows FROM sys.tables T JOIN sys.sysindexes I ON T.OBJECT_ID =
>   I.ID WHERE indid IN (0,1) ORDER BY i.Rows DESC,T.name

Means you are looking for tables, and their respective indexes, for tables that are either a heap (i.e. has no index) or have a clustered index. I'm not sure why this would classify as an "error". I'd expect you to want to look for only heaps. i.e. on where `indid = 0`. Regardless, I suppose the "fixed" would be to return tables that, for example, didn't have a clustered index which now does. In that case I don't understand the schema and think you have asked a **[XY Question](http://xyproblem.info/)**

With that being said,based off the other comments, you could use derived tables and join on the literal values of `error.tablename` to prevent the use of a cursor.

```
select 
   error.tablename
   ,error.errorcnt
   ,fixed = coalesce(t1.ct, t2.ct) --add in for each join. 
from 
    error
left join (select count(fixed) as ct from table1 where fixed = 'Y') as t1 on error.tablename = 'table1'
left join (select count(fixed) as ct from table2 where fixed = 'Y') as t2 on error.tablename = 'table2'
--continue the joins for all values in error.tablename
```

A cursor would be less code, and dynamic, but you asked for a way *without* a cursor.

Comment: the Tables it is pulling from are only the rows that have errors. so i can use the rowcount as the errorcoung value.  ok i see where your going but the number of tables changes location to locations, location 1 could have 40 tables Location 2 could have 23 tables, location 3 could have 145 tables...So i think a cursor might be my only way?

Comment: Most likely, based on what I can gather. Generally speaking, you'll need some dynamic way and a cursor seems like the only solution here since you will be passing in table names to dynamic sql most likely.

Comment: did you figure it out @LeeHopkins

Answer (score 0):

you can use temp table and while loop avoid cursor

```
DECLARE
    @SQLQuery   NVARCHAR(100),
    @Tablename  VARCHAR(100)

CREATE TABLE
    #error
(
    tablename   VARCHAR(100),
    errorcnt    INT
)

CREATE TABLE
    #Table1
(
    fixed       INT
)

CREATE TABLE
    #Table2
(
    fixed       INT
)

CREATE TABLE
    #Temp_fixed
(
    fixed       INT
)

INSERT INTO
    #error
VALUES
(
    '#Table1',
    5
),
(
    '#Table2',
    256
)

INSERT INTO
    #Table1
VALUES
(
    3
)

INSERT INTO
    #Table2
VALUES
(
    239
)

SELECT
    tablename,
    errorcnt,
    -1 AS fixed
INTO
    #Temp_error
FROM
    #error

WHILE EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM #Temp_error WHERE fixed = -1)
    BEGIN

        SET
            @Tablename = (SELECT TOP 1 tablename FROM #Temp_error WHERE fixed = -1)
        SET
            -- @SQLQuery = 'SELECT COUNT(fixed) FROM ' + @Tablename
            @SQLQuery = 'SELECT SUM(fixed) FROM ' + @Tablename

        INSERT INTO
            #Temp_fixed
        (
            fixed
        )
        EXECUTE
            sp_executesql
                @SQLQuery

        UPDATE
            #Temp_error
        SET
            fixed = ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 fixed FROM #Temp_fixed), 0)
        WHERE
            tablename = @Tablename

        TRUNCATE TABLE #Temp_fixed

    END

SELECT
    tablename,
    errorcnt,
    fixed
FROM
    #Temp_error


DROP TABLE #error
DROP TABLE #Table1
DROP TABLE #Table2
DROP TABLE #Temp_error
DROP TABLE #Temp_fixed
```